# Can I create a custom N1QL secondary index with spring-data-couchbase from within application code?

Tags: indexing, spring-boot, couchdb, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I created a Global Secondary Index in couchbase by hand running:

```
CREATE INDEX custom_index ON `my-bucket`(field_name) 
USING GSI 
WITH {"nodes": ["localhost:8091"]}
```

I have a spring boot application. Is there a way that this index can be automatically created with spring-data-couchbase? A desired behaviour would be as follows: at application startup, if the index doesn't exist to be created. As far as I read the only secondary index that can be automatically created is the `@N1qlSecondaryIndexed` which indexes based on the `_class` field.

Answer (score 1):

A warning first:
This is not something that is usually recommended by couchbase support, mainly because if one node in the cluster is down and it is the one that holds the index, your app will recreate a duplicate index on another node, which can be problematic.

That's why the `@N1qlSecondaryIndexed` thing is opt-in (you have to also change the configuration to activate it).

There's no automatic and direct way of creating your particular index, but you can access the underlying SDK so you can do it from within the Spring Boot `Application`.

Inject a reference to the `Bucket` (I'm assuming you're configuring Spring to use *my_bucket* by default) and use the index management API on the `BucketManager`:

```
bucket.bucketManager().createN1qlIndex("custom_index", true, false, "field_name");
```

The parameters to this method are the index name, ignore the "index already exist error", don't defer creation and then the fields to index (as described in  the [javadoc](http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-2.3.3/com/couchbase/client/java/bucket/BucketManager.html#createN1qlIndex-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-java.lang.Object...-)).